# how to agroup SKShapeNodes in swift sprite kit

Tags: xcode, swift, skshapenode

SWIFT - Sprite Kit

I need to create columns of 2 or more SKShapeNodes. I need to agroup them because each column of nodes will have an action.

I know how to create the shapenodes of rectangles but i dont know how to agroup the shapenodes and have one column with shapenodes..

here i will post a photo because i dont speak english verry well for you to understand me

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create a parent-node for each group:

```
var xPosiColumn1:CGFloat = 100
var firstGroup = SKSpriteNode()
firstGroup.position = CGPointMake(xPosiColumn1, self.frame.width/2)
```

Then, you add the nodes to your group:

```
var firstNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40, 100))
var secondNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40, 40))
var thirdNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40, 100))

firstNode.position = yourPosition
//... second etc...

firstGroup.addChild(firstNode)
firstGroup.addChild(secondNode)
firstGroup.addChild(thirdNode)
```

You then have to set the position for your inner nodes(first, second, third). You don't have to set the x position, because the position is relative to the parent-node. So you only have to set the y position.

```
firstNode.position.y = 100
```

It's important to know that the `SKSpriteNode` coordinate 0/0 is in the center of the node.

As you see, I use SKSpriteNode instead of SKShapeNode. I would highly recommend you to use `SKSpriteNode` because you've got much more possibilities. But you can do the same with SKShapeNodes of course.

Comment: Thank you VERRY VERRY much. I understand it perfect.

Comment: and if you can help me with another question, please and sorry. I need to create those columns in a time interval of 2.0 (waitforduration), and i need those columns to be created randomly, example: column one, wait 2 secs, column 3, wait 2 secs, column 2, wait 2 secs, column 3... from the right to the left. I already know how to move the columns but i dont know how to create them randomly and set the time interval. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. For your other problem you should ask another . Because it's another problem.